# How do you harvest carrots in creative mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing creative mode (Java edition, Windows 10) and can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to harvest carrots. I've planted them and they've grown to the point that a little bit of orange is sticking out. They're not growing any further, so I'm pretty sure they're ready to be picked.

Right-clicking does nothing. If I left-click, it just smashes the carrots together with the soil underneath. Or is it that carrot patches don't always yield carrots?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**You can**.  But it isn't as easy as survival mode. [As UnionHawk said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/356547/228910) clicking on the crop block will destroy it in creative mode. Instead, you can use flowing water to break the crops. Likewise, you can use pistons to push the crops which will also break the crop block and allow the food to be collected.

Not all foods can be harvested using these methods. For instance, pumpkins and melons are not affected by flowing water. For the purpose of harvesting carrots this should not be an issue, however.

While you cannot harvest by hand, there are other ways to collect your crops.

Answer (score 7):

**You can't**. The normal way to harvest crops in vanilla is to left click to break them, which drops the harvest similar to mining a block. In creative mode, you always destroy blocks you break. There is no way to harvest crops in creative mode.

Comment: Well, technically you can by creating a water block, letting it run over the farm and destroy it. This will cause crops to pop out of ground and be harvested. Mostly. And it's not really "harvesting" either..

Comment: Right clicking crops will also harvest them, and replant as well, unless that's a mod that i've literally never played without... (a possibility, as I've encountered things before that I didn't know weren't vanilla.)

Comment: @Hearth I'm fairly sure that's a mod, but if it isn't, that apparently does not work in creative mode per the asker.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to just jump onto the crop, but it does turn the soil back to dirt, so have your hoe ready so you can re-fertalize the soil, I find jumping much simpler than water, and you only need to jump in place a few times